# Should a regex question be posted on SO or Programmers Exchange?

Tags: discussion, posting

I have some questions about specific regex expressions and problems. Which area is best suited for that type of question?

Comment: I would be very surprised if this were suitable for Programmers.SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [the faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) to see which questions are acceptable on each particular site.

*Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in **subjective** questions on software development*

So, whether your question is about regex or Java or Lua is immaterial.

Comment: Thank You.  The faq explained it perfectly.